# Loop through a JSON file, add element then save to new file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON file consisting of elements like so :

```
var data=[{
    "Name": "Jeff",
    "Age": 35
},
{
    "Name": "cliff",
    "Age": 56
}]
```

I want to add another field, say 'Country'. So it looks something like this :

```
var data=[{
    "Name": "Jeff",
    "Age": 35,
    "Country" : "USA"
},
{
    "Name": "cliff",
    "Age": 56,
    "Country" : "UK"
}]
```

I have hundreds of elements so it would take too long to do it by hand. How would I loop through the JSON adding another element as shown above and then print this to a text file which saves to another file which I can use.

Comment: How the script will determine what to use for "Country"? Please consider improving your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this

```js
data=[{
 "Name": "Jeff",
 "Age": 35
},
{
 "Name": "cliff",
 "Age": 56
}];
for(var index in data){
 var obj=data[index];
 switch('USA'){
  case'USA': 
   obj['Country']='USA';
   break;
  case'UK': 
   obj['Country']='UK';
   break;
 }
}
document.write(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: I just figured it out as you answered :) I've answered too, but shall except yours as you have conditions which will help me too :) Thanks

Comment: your answer has a mistake data is array of arrays so you should use data[0].length in loop

Comment: I get undefined when trying to do that. I tried logging it like so : console.log(data[0].length) .... I get undefined ?

Comment: oh btw, appreciate the answer but as the question asked, do you know how to save this to text file ? With the new data

Comment: write the output to browser with document.write

Comment: where does that save to ?

Comment: it will write to the browser window. you can copy that save it to text file

Comment: try the example attached

Comment: I was going to say it didnt work when using data[0], but youve made the adjustment. I also used console.log() instead of document.write() as I'm a noob and cant find where it's outputted :P But still its working great, thanks mate :))

Answer (score 1):

Me being lazy, I've figured it out :

```
var newData = data;
    for(i=0; i<newData.length;i++){
      var country = "Country " + i; //just for testing

      newData[i].country = country;
      console.log(newData[i].country);

    }
console.log(newData); //this logs the whole JSON to console which i copied and pasted to local json text file :)
```